# How to float "center"?? I know that's not right, I want a left, center, and right section of a nav bar

Tags: html, css

I have a menu bar at the top of an application with 3 sections.  Icons on the left, Icons in the center, and an icon on the right.  I can easily float left and float right the respective sections, but I don't know how to float a center section.

I have attached screen shots of the desired outcome, and what I am currently getting.

The problem is that the number of icons in the left and center sections will change all the time.
This is my Desired outcome
[image: Desired Outcome]

vs
My actual Outcome
[image: Actual Outcome]

I am using the same icons in my example, but the left is in the correct place, the logout button is on the correct side, but pushed down, the middle section is all screwed up.

Thank you for any help.

```
<body>
<div id="content">
    <div id="menuBar">
        <div id="menuBarContent">
            <div class="homeIconDiv menuBarHardIconDiv floatLeft">
                <img class="menuBarIcon" src="images/icons/home.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="backIconDiv menuBarHardIconDiv floatLeft">
                <img class="menuBarIcon" src="images/icons/home.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="menuBarSoftIconDiv">
                <img class="menuBarIcon" src="images/icons/home.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="menuBarSoftIconDiv">
                <img class="menuBarIcon" src="images/icons/home.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="logoutIconDiv" class="floatRight">
                <img class="logoutIcon" src="images/icons/logoutButton.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainContent" class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
html
{
    height:100%;
}

body
{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}


 .MSIQtextbox { 
    border: 1px solid #67AE3D; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
    border-radius: 10px; 
    outline:0; 
    height:35px; 
    width: 375px; 
    padding-left:10px; 
    padding-right:10px; 
  }

.floatLeft 
{
    float:left;
}

.floatRight 
{
    float:right;
}

.center
{
     text-align:center;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.clear
{
    clear:both;
}
#content
{
    height:100%;
}

#menuBar 
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    background-color:rgba(211,211,211,0.9);  
    height:64px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #888888;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    z-index:10000;
    width:100%;
}

#menuBarContent
{
    width:1020px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#mainContent 
{
    width:1020px;
    min-height:630px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:100%;
    padding-top:3px;
}

.optionsDiv
{
    color:White;
}

.menuBarHardIconDiv 
{
    height:64px;
    width:64px;
    border-right:1px solid #858585;
}

#logoutIconDiv 
{
    height:64px;
}

.menuBarHardIconDiv:hover
{
 background-color:#F5F0E0;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #888888;
}

img.menuBarIcon
{
   position:relative;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   margin-top:-12px;
   margin-left:-12px;
}

img.logoutIcon
{
   position:relative;
   top:50%;
   margin-top:-12px;
}
```

Comment: You must specify a `width` to use `margin:0 auto` for the `.center`container.

Answer (score -1):

.center {margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}